# Is In-Memory a extra-cost option? (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, in-memory-database, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

I’m a spatial data analyst trying to learn about options for [pre-computing columns](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/automation-options-in-arcgis-computing-a-field/m-p/1174800) in Oracle 18c.

I've recently learned about Oracle’s In-Memory technology as a possible option:

> [Oracle 21c - Database In-Memory Support by Oracle Spatial](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/spatial-concepts.html#GUID-ED5EBC37-DE65-4DFC-B8C1-2E602D78C0ED)
>
> Spatial supports the use of Oracle Database In-Memory technology.
>
> You can enable a spatial table for use with Database In-Memory by
> adding virtual columns, and then use operators such as SDO_FILTER to
> query that table without using a spatial index.

Question:

Is In-Memory an extra-cost add-on to Oracle? Or is it included as standard functionality in all implementations of Oracle 18c Enterprise?

I tried asking in the [Oracle **In-Memory** community](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4498408/is-in-memory-a-paid-option/), but didn't get a response.

Comment: Yes, that expensive ditty is not free. The code's there to use (as of 12c) but if you use it and don't pay for it, then bad stuff happens. They're not exactly the nicest people on the earth.

Comment: @JeffHolt Thanks! Yeah, James Gosling (creator of Java) refers to Oracle as *rapacious*: [James Gosling: Java, JVM, Emacs, and the Early Days of Computing | Lex Fridman Podcast #126](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IT__Nrr3PNI).

Comment: I'm as guilty as the next guy as having a favourite but I would never pick Oracle as my db. Complicated expensive licencing. Complicated DBA procedures. They've spent the last few decades gouging people that haven't been able to get off their platform. I don't know what your requirements are but may I suggest SQL Server instead :D https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 BTW "In memory" was a bit of a fad a few years ago. Generally if your database is small enough to fit in memory, that's where it is.

Comment: There's a significant difference between an in-memory database system and database that happens to be in memory e.g. by virtue of caching.

Comment: The big value in Oracle's In Memory option is their use SIMD machine instructions and the fact that the data have only to be stored once in the database. The translation from row orientation to column orientation is automatic when you load the table (or partitions). It's brilliant and the resulting speed increases are mind boggling. It's an awesome implementation but very costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer questions like this, check the [Database Licensing Information User Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-B6113390-9586-46D7-9008-DCC9EDA45AB4).

Which has this to say about In-Memory in 18c:

> Oracle Database In-Memory ... EE and EE-ES: Extra cost option

So yes, it's extra cost. [From 19.8](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87) there is the [Database In-Memory Base Level feature](https://blogs.oracle.com/in-memory/post/questions-you-asked-database-in-memory-base-level-feature). This includes In-Memory access in Enterprise Edition subject to these restrictions:

> Allows you to experiment with Oracle Database In-Memory features
> without purchasing the Oracle Database In-Memory option. The following
> restrictions apply:
>
> - The size of the In-Memory area (INMEMORY_SIZE) cannot exceed 16 GB for a CDB. In an Oracle RAC environment, the size is limited to 16 GB
>   for each instance.
> - The compression level for all objects and columns is automatically and transparently set to QUERY LOW.
> - The Automatic In-Memory feature is disabled.
> - In-Memory Column Store feature tracking is tracked for "In-Memory Base Level" rather than "In-Memory Column Store."
> - The CellMemory feature is disabled for Oracle Exadata.

If you're using 18c, please note that it entered [Sustaining Support on 30th June 2021](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/742060_1.html). To stay supported you really should be looking to upgrade to 19c.